# How to read TLS version of HTTPS connection in Jetty?

Tags: java, ssl, https, jetty

I embedded Jetty server into my application. In my application I can read cipher-suite it negotiated by reading `javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite` of request attributes. Now I want to check if my clients use TLSv1.0, TLSv.1.1 or TLSv.1.2. If I enable debugging of SSL I can see it on my console:

```
qtp2819825-43, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 8038
```

But how can I read it in my `handler()`?

I studied both `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request` and `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`. There is `getProtocol()` method but it returns `HTTP/1.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Jetty 9.3 I can read TLS version by:

```
    SSLSession sslSession = (SSLSession)request.getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.request.ssl_session");
    if (sslSession == null)
        env.set("SSL_PROTOCOL_VERSION", "NULL");
    else
        env.set("SSL_PROTOCOL_VERSION", sslSession.getProtocol());
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is open for a while but since there is an answer now it might be relevant for others.

You can configure your ServerConnector by adding a `SecureRequestCustomizer` to its HttpConfiguration. An example can be found at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056304/in-the-jetty-server-how-can-i-obtain-the-client-certificate-used-when-client-aut), but there are many more [out there](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer).

When setting this customizer, informations are added as attributes, you can retrieve from the HttpServletRequest. The complete SSLSession was added as result of a ["bugreport"](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/85) and is available at least with versions >= 9.3. The default attribute name is `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.request.ssl_session` but you can set it yourself in your configuation by calling `setSslSessionAttribute("your.attribute.name")`