# How to get the client's certificate in jetty server when doing authentication

Tags: ssl, jetty, embedded-jetty, sslcontext

After set an embedded Jetty server that requests client authentication by setting SslContextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(true), how can I get the client's certificate information when a client connect to jetty server for both cases, the authentication successful and failed?

I have read this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056304/in-the-jetty-server-how-can-i-obtain-the-client-certificate-used-when-client-aut) but I think this is only applicable for the authentication successful. `SecureRequestCustomizer.customize(...)` seems only executed after client's certificate information is authenticated successfully.

But what i am wondering is there any approach to get the client's certificate information when jetty server is doing authentication, no matter it is successful or failed. Then I can get the client's certificate information even this client is not trusted by jetty sever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

When you have `SslContextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(true)` set, that means you are setting the Java level `javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters.setNeedClientAuth(true)`.

This impacts the Java level TLS/SSL negotiation of new connections, and forces them to require a valid Client Certificate.

If that fails, the connection is terminated by Java itself at the TLS/SSL handshake level, and no HTTP request is even sent by the client, and Jetty has not been involved in this determination.

As you have no-doubt already noticed, a connection that has failed the TLS/SSL level Client Authentication is not processed in the `SecureRequestCustomizer`.

If you want to see successful *and failed* clients get past the TLS/SSL handshake level and reach your various HTTP handlers then you'll have to turn off the `SslContextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(true)` setting.   But that means there is no client certificate authentication performed by the Java JVM's TLS/SSL layers, and you are now on the hook to perform these same checks in your own code.  This wont work very well.

So you have a choice of ...

1. `setNeedClientAuth(true)` - Connection is authenticated, terminated if client certificate failed.  No HTTP request is created by client.
2. `setNeedClientAuth(false)` - All connections succeed with no authentication being performed, resulting in HTTP requests that you can then process.

If you need point 1, but point 2 is no-go, consider using the `org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslHandshakeListener` and just paying attention to the results of success/failure.

Create your own implementation of this listener, and add it as a bean to your server Connectors.  You'll get passed the active `javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine` for that event source, where you can interrogate the various details you are after for a failed connection (you can even get the IP information of the client that attempted the connection)

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what i want.

Comment: Hi @Joakim, I have tried, but when ssl handshake failed, I cannot get any information from SSLEngine.  I get the SSLSession, `SSLSession session = event.getSSLEngine().getSession();`, but when i get other information with `session.getPeerCertificates()`, `session.getPeerCertificateChain()`, it all throws `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated`. When ssl handshake is ok, I can get the certificates information with above two methods. Do you know anything about it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Be aware that `session.getPeerCertificateChain()` is deprecated, use the recommended alternatives indicated in javadoc, and pay attention to the javadoc on the recommended paths about what SSLPeerUnverifiedException means, especially around specific cipher suites features.

Comment: I checked, I used the right cipher, and try with `getPeerCertificates()` but still no certificates found. The javadoc of this method said `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` will be thrown `if the peer's identity has not been verified`. So i am afraid i cannot get peer identity when authentication failed.

Comment: I tried with initiating an `SslContextFactory` setting with an `SSLContex` initialized myself with `X509TrustManager` and `X509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] var1, String var2)` override, in this methd i can directly printout the certificates information no matter peer is authencated or not. Luckly, this works. But do you foresee any risk with homemade SSLContext in Jetty